# Using enum class write the factory method

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums, factory

I need to use `enum class` and factory method with `static` function `create` to be able to create the appropriate type of `Object`

```
enum class Object
{
   First,
   Second,
   Third
};
```

Each object has `function1`, `function2` and `function3`.

I searched about enum class and factory method but don't know how to combine them.

Comment: being more specific about your problem would be helpful

Comment: I see only an enum. What you have tried to achieve your goals? Currently this question looks like "Please write my code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite common to parameterize a factory method, say an `Object` factory named `Object::create()`, over a *tag*, e.g. over a non-type template parameter such as an enum, say `ObjectTag`. The `Object::create()` function template parameterized over `ObjectTag` exposes a public factory method that is specialized for each specific enumerator of the `ObjectTag` enum, and which in turn use e.g. a private constructor of `Object` that is not exposed in its public API.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class ObjectTag
{
   kFirst,
   kSecond,
   kThird
};

struct Object {
    template <ObjectTag TAG>
    static Object create() = delete;

    void foo() const { std::cout << foo_ << "\n"; }

private:
    explicit Object(const int foo) : foo_(foo) {}
    int foo_;
};

template<>
Object Object::create<ObjectTag::kFirst>() { return Object(11); }

template<>
Object Object::create<ObjectTag::kSecond>() { return Object(22); }

template<>
Object Object::create<ObjectTag::kThird>() { return Object(33); }

int main() {
    const auto a = Object::create<ObjectTag::kFirst>();
    const auto b = Object::create<ObjectTag::kSecond>();
    const auto c = Object::create<ObjectTag::kThird>();
    a.foo();  // 11
    b.foo();  // 22
    c.foo();  // 33
}
```

Note that the primary template of the member function template `Object::create()` has been deleted, such that there exists definitions only of the (full) explicit specializations of it.